# Array.map() and Array.forEach() return original array

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    let grid = req.body.dayGrid

    grid.map(week => {
        week.map(day => {
            return day+'!'
        })
    })

    res.json(grid)
})
```

Why does this code return the original array without the appended '!'?

The same happens with Array.forEach()

Comment: You are creating a new array but you aren't assigning it to anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `map` is not replacing original object, it's returning the new one.

```js
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    let grid = req.body.dayGrid

    grid = grid.map(week => week.map(day => day+'!'))

    res.json(grid)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the original grid array from the request body.
 Try this

```js
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    let grid = req.body.dayGrid

     const result = grid.map(week => {
        return week.map(day => {
            return day+'!'
        })
    })

    res.json(result)
})
```